Setting exit code in launch Shutdown event
At the moment there is no way to shut down deployment with a custom exit code. At least not to my knowledge. Well, not in a clean way with an exit code other than 0.
I have the following use-case:
def on_exit(event, *_):
  if event.returncode:
    return launch.actions.EmitEvent(event=launch.events.Shutdown(reason='Node failed!'))

return launch.LaunchDescription([
  launch_ros.actions.Node(
    # ...
    on_exit = on_exit,
  )
])

So, if my node fails I'll cleanly shutdown the application, but the exit code of the application is still going to be 0. And I want to signal that the application failed. Exit code 1 could work, but being able to set up a custom exit-code would be nice.
A simple, hacky, alternative is to do the following:
def on_exit(event, *_):
  if event.returncode:
    raise RuntimeError('Node failed!')

Then the application exits cleanly with exit-code 1.
So, would adding exit_code to Shutdown event be welcomed? If so, can I get some guidance for this one? If not, what would be alternatives? Thanks in advance.
I am currently using ROS 2 Humble.
